# how to create Thread poolling using Spring scheduler?

Tags: spring

I want a sample for thread pooling using Spring scheduler?

Comment: you might want to rephrase the question a bit, it's not very clear if you're looking for a TheadPoolTaskExecutor (which is not a TaskScheduler)

Answer (score 0):

See the [The Spring TaskExecutor abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor), use the [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html). It is configured as follows:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>
```

Comment: how to initialize taskExecutor with tasks at startups in case of a web application?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to be sure what you want, but you could use the `ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean` to create a standard Java5 `ScheduledExecutorService` which has comprehensive scheduling functions.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring 3, the task namespace was added it contains what you need to setup a pooled TaskExecutor:

```
<task:executor id="executorWithCallerRunsPolicy"
           pool-size="5-25"
           queue-capacity="100"
           rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

You can read http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html for details.